# React Native: Navigation is not working properly after eject from Expo

Tags: ios, reactjs, react-native, react-native-navigation

I am developing an app with React Native and Expo and all has been working fine until I ejected the app.
Now the root `SwitchNavigator` is not operating as intended, at least on iOS.

I have 3 possible main Routes `AuthLoading`, `Auth`, `Main` as shown below:

```
import { createAppContainer, createSwitchNavigator } from "react-navigation";

import MainTabNavigator from "./MainTabNavigator";
import AuthLoadingScreen from "../screens/auth/AuthLoadingScreen";
import AuthStack from "./auth/AuthStack";
import TestScreen from "../screens/TestScreen";

export default createAppContainer(
  createSwitchNavigator(
    {
      AuthLoading: AuthLoadingScreen,
      Auth: AuthStack,
      Test: TestScreen,
      Main: MainTabNavigator
    },
    {
      headerMode: "none",
      initialRouteName: "AuthLoading"
    }
  )
);
```

Unless I comment out the last route it will always move there.

**Using**

React Native Expo SDK: 36.0.1

React Navigation: 3.12.0

React Native: 0.61

Comment: Hello Igor, I could not clearly understand what is your problem?

Comment: @FreakyCoder the main SwitchNavigator is not working as expected. I have the aforementioned routes registered but the “Main” is always the one rendered. Even if I set the initialRouteName explicitly

Comment: Okay, got it. Can you share the whole navigation js file? and which RN version are you using? Also which React Navigation version are you using?

Comment: @FreakyCoder I have updated the question to contemplate the whole file (not much), and the versions you asked. Ty in advance

Comment: Igor there is no 36.0.1 version of React Native. It should something like 0.61.5(latest). Can you check again?

Comment: @FreakyCoder sorry, I meant the Expo SDK version

Comment: However you eject the expo, can you tell me the React Native version?

Comment: @FreakyCoder The Expo SDK 36 uses React Native 0.61